# Customize Touch Bar with Function Keys

Tags: macbook-pro, big-sur, touch-bar

I need to customize my Touch Bar such that it shows Function keys by default but upon holding the fn key it should show app control and control strip (media controls) together just like how it is in normal default

In settings there is no way to show both app control and control strip (media controls) as a second setting

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused. In Big Sur, the main tab of the Keyboard preference pane in the System Preferences app looks like this:

[image]

If you set the **"Touch Bar Shows"** and **"Press and hold Fn keys to"** pulldown menus as shown, you should get the result you want.

Comment: What I meant is, in **"Touch Bar Shows"** there is an option to "Show App Controls" and along with that a checkbox is there to show Control Strip. Is it possible to get it in **"Press and Hold fn keys to"**

Comment: @sidewala: Ah, sorry, I misunderstood. I don't see a way to make that happen, but I'll look around a bit.